# Парсинг Jsoup картинок и проблема памяти

Tags: android, парсер, jsoup, bitmap, memory

Привет! Мне нужна ваша помощь.

Пишу приложение на Android, где по при помощи jsoup парсится ссылка на текстовый файл, в которым ссылки на страницы форума. Файл и ссылки в нем мною периодически обновляются извне.

```
class ParseMyPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            input = new URL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/akhorevich/5b849373dc9abaf921b3/raw/18e79ab6a0c0be007a2a4590e4e176184ced311a/links");

            sc = new Scanner(input.openStream());
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String link = sc.nextLine();

                doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
               Elements names = doc.select("div.node-title");
              // Elements images = doc.select("div.node div.content img");
                Elements imgs = doc.select("div.node div.content img");

                for (Element img : imgs) {

                    Element myImage = img;
                    String imgSrc = myImage.attr("src");
                    InputStream inp = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                    // Decode Bitmap
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inp);
                    allImages.add(bitmap);

                }


                for(Element name: names) {
                    mData.add(name.text());

                }

                if(mData.size() == 0) {
                    mData.add("Empty result");
                }

            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mData.clear();
            mData.add("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
        return text; // получаем весь текст
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        sectorC_adapter = new SectorC_Adapter(getActivity());
        mListView.setAdapter(sectorC_adapter);

    }
}
class SectorC_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context c;

    SectorC_Adapter(Context c){
        this.c = c;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView==null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)c
                    .getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sector_row, parent,false);
        }else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        tvInfo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dog_name);
        tvInfo.setText(mData.get(position).toString());
        dog_view = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.dog_view);
        dog_view.setImageBitmap(allImages.get(position));
        return row;
    }
}
```

Примерно так это все выглядит.
Но есть две проблемы -

1. Картинки парсятся только из первой ссылки в файле (у меня конкретно собаки - допустим во все элементы вставляются разные фотки Жучки, а нужно чтоб каждой ссылке соответствовала своя фотка собаки)
2. Вторая проблема - слишком это жрет память и приложение периодически "падает". Можно ли как то фотографии грузить в буфер или на карту или куда еще, а потом подгружать?

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается второй проблемы - да, можно. Когда парсите страницу, не надо грузить сразу же фото в оперативную память, если нужно сохранить на устройстве, то скачайте на внутреннюю память или sd карту, а потом чтобы показать возьмите от туда. Или можно просто хранить ссылку на картинку, а грузить ее непосредственно в момент отображения.
Для второго способа существует куча библиотек:
[Новомодная от фэйсбука](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html#_)
[Удобная и мощная](https://github.com/koush/ion)
[старая и проверенная picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: спасибо. Первый вопрос более важен ибо качать надо нужно фотки, а не мусорить приложение.

Comment: @akhorevich опишите первую проблему более развернуто

Comment: [screen](http://s57.radikal.ru/i155/1504/4e/3175be5f9f65.png) Выглядит оно примерно так. На фотках - одна и та же собака из первой ссылки, приложение парсит 10 ее фоток. Надо чтоб из каждой ссылки парсило 1ю фотку и втавляло в свой item

Comment: @akhorevich так у вас логика нарушена. советую для начала переделать ваше решение так, как я описал в ответе. В новом виде будет проще разобраться с логикой. создайте более удобную модель данных для хранения информации об одном элементе и пихайте туда всю необходимую информацию

Comment: Спасибо, @andreich, я все решила.)